# How to align the typing to the center in the UserInfoPage?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

As the question says I want to start typing from the center instead of starting from the left.

A short code value:

```pascal
with WizardForm.UserInfoNameEdit do
begin
  Left := ScaleX(104);
  Top := ScaleY(182);
  Width := ScaleX(233);
  Height := ScaleY(31);
  Font.Height := -19;
  MaxLength := 30;
  ParentFont := False;
end;
```

here some images:

[image: Exemples]

[image: Exemples]

Comment: No it's not possible. And it looks like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: [See image](http://i.imgur.com/iJaU4cz.png).

Comment: That's what I mean by terrible idea. Follow Windows GUI style. Do not invent your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your third picture you may use a custom form and position your controls in the center of your form.

```pascal
function CreateMyCustomUserDialog(): Boolean; 
var
    Form: TSetupForm;
    OKButton, CancelButton: TNewButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
begin
  Form := CreateCustomForm();
  try
    Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
    Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(256);
    Form.Caption := 'User Information';
    Form.CenterInsideControl(WizardForm, true);

    OKButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    OKButton.Parent := Form;
    OKButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    OKButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 6 + 75 + 10);
    OKButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    OKButton.Caption := 'OK';
    OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk;

    Label1 := TLabel.Create(Form);
    Label1.Parent := Form;
    Label1.Alignment := taCenter;
    Label1.Caption := 'Username:';
    Label1.Width := Form.ClientWidth;
    Label1.Height := ScaleY(23);    
    Label1.Top := 30;    

    Edit1 := TEdit.Create(Form);
    Edit1.Parent := Form;
    Edit1.Top := 50;
    Edit1.Width := 100;
    Edit1.Left := (Form.ClientWidth -  Edit1.Width) / 2;
    Edit1.Text := 'Admin';           

    CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    CancelButton.Parent := Form;
    CancelButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    CancelButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 10);
    CancelButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel';
    CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
    CancelButton.Cancel := True;

    Form.ActiveControl := OKButton;

    if Form.ShowModal() = mrOk then
      MsgBox('You clicked OK.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  finally
    Form.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete. However I see you are using WizardForm.UserInfoPage; as parent form. So why don't you try something like that on controls you want to center.

`Left := (WizardForm.UserInfoPage.ClientWidth -  Width) / 2;`